# Make multiple @pytest.mark.parametrize with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I was looking for how to make a double `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

This wrapper has a great advantage because it allows you to test an assert on a parameter and move to the next parameters if it is false.

I would like to make a double `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to compare two tables:

```py
excepted = {"Parametre 1":{"Objet 1":"Yes","Objet 2":"Yes","Objet 3":"Yes"},"Parametre 2":{"Objet 1":"No","Objet 2":"Yes","Objet 3":"Yes"}}
obtained = {"Parametre 1":{"Objet 1":"Non","Objet 2":"Yes","Objet 3":"Yes"},"Parametre 2":{"Objet 1":"No","Objet 2":"Yes","Objet 3":"Yes"}}
```

[my tables :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3OPh.png)

```
excepted : 
         Parametre 1 Parametre 2
Objet 1         Yes          No
Objet 2         Yes         Yes
Objet 3         Yes         Yes

obtained : 
         Parametre 1 Parametre 2
Objet 1         Non          No
Objet 2         Yes         Yes
Objet 3         Yes         Yes
```

- for each object:

  - test all columns.

Like the following method:

```py
import pytest
import pandas as pd
@pytest.mark.parametrize("objet", ['Objet 1', 'Objet 2', 'Objet 3'])
def object_test(objet: str):
    obtained = pd.DataFrame(obtained)
    assert objet in obtained.index.values
    excepted = pd.DataFrame(excepted)
    for column in results.columns:
        obtained_cell = obtained.loc[objet][column]
        excepted_cell = excepted.loc[objet][column]
        test_cell(objet, obtained_cell, excepted_cell)


def test_cell(object_name, obtained_cell, excepted_cell):
    if excepted_cell  == 'Yes':
        assert obtained_cell == excepted_cell, f"{object_name}"
    else:
    if obtained_cell == 'Yes':
        warnings.warn(UserWarning(f"bad annotation"))
```

I would add above `test_cell`

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(["object_name, obtained_cell, excepted_cell"], object_test())
def test_cell(object_name, obtained_cell, excepted_cell):
```

But I can't because I have to specify value object for my function

Comment: How can i show a glimpse of my tables like output dataFrame?

Comment: see : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, you need to pass each item from 3 different entities in a parameterized fashion. This can be achieved easily using the same parametrize fixture.

From the [official doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions), you can do something like this:

```py
def object_test(objet: str):    # not sure from where you'd pass this
    obtained = pd.DataFrame(obtained)    # not sure how you'd access `obtained`
    assert objet in obtained.index.values
    excepted = pd.DataFrame(excepted)
    for column in results.columns:
        obtained_cell = obtained.loc[objet][column]
        excepted_cell = excepted.loc[objet][column]
        yield (objet, obtained_cell, excepted_cell)  # THIS IS WHAT YOU DO

@pytest.mark.parametrize("object_name,obtained_cell,excepted_cell", object_test())
def test_cell(object_name, obtained_cell, excepted_cell):
    assert object_name
```

Exmaple:

```py
def object():
    for x in range(5):
        yield (x, x**2, x**3)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x,y,z", object())
def test_me(x, y, z):
    assert x ** 2 == y
    assert x ** 3 == z
```

`$ pytest tests/test_me.py`

```
tests/test_me.py::test_me[0-0-0] PASSED                                [ 20%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[1-1-1] PASSED                                [ 40%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[2-4-8] PASSED                                [ 60%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[3-9-27] PASSED                               [ 80%]
tests/test_me.py::test_me[4-16-64] PASSED                              [100%]
```